# Suppose $T \in L(V)$ is invertible. Prove that $G(\lambda, T)=G(\frac{1}{\lambda},T^{-1})$ for every $\lambda \in \mathbf{F}$ with $\lambda \neq 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T \in L(V)$ is invertible. Prove that $G(\lambda, T)=G(\frac{1}{\lambda},T^{-1})$ for every $\lambda \in \mathbf{F}$ with $\lambda \neq 0$.

It is a problem from Ex8.A, Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd.

The $G(\lambda, T)$ represents the generalized eigenspace.

I tried to express T and T inverse in matrixes, but I'm confused.

So, please help me! Thank you a lot. :)

---

The definitions are here:
[From Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd, Page 245](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PROJS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** Note that for $\lambda\neq0$ and any integer $k$ you have
$$(T^{-1}-\tfrac{1}{\lambda}I)^k=(-1)^k\frac{1}{\lambda^k}T^{-k}(T-\lambda I)^k.$$

---

In more detail; if $\lambda\neq0$ and $v\in G(\lambda,T)$ then there is some integer $k$ such that $(T-\lambda I)^kv=0$. Multiplying by $\lambda^{-k}T^{-k}$ then shows that
$$0=\lambda^{-k}T^{-k}(T-\lambda I)^kv=(\lambda^{-1}T^{-1}(T-\lambda I))^kv=(\lambda^{-1}I-T^{-1})^kv,$$
which implies that $v\in G(\lambda^{-1},T^{-1})$. This shows that $G(\lambda,T)\subseteq G(\lambda^{-1},T^{-1})$. The proof of the other inclusion is identical.

Comment: But $(T^{-1}-\frac{1}{\lambda} I)$ is not the inverse of $(T-\lambda I)$?

Comment: Could you please tell me more?

Comment: Sorry, but is $T(v)=\lambda v$ true for a generalized eigenvector $v$?

Comment: Ah I didn't read your question thoroughly enough. Roughly the same argument works though, I'll edit in a minute.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't follow you in $\lambda ^{-k}T^{-k} (T−\lambda I)^{k}v=(\lambda ^{-1} T^{-1} (T−\lambda I))^{k} v$. I thought we need to show that the multiplication for $T^{-1}$ and $(T−\lambda I)$ holds the commutative law. I am not quite sure, could you please say something about that? Thanks. :)

Comment: Every matrix commutes with its own inverse, and with every scalar matrix $\lambda I$.

Comment: OK, I got it. Thanks.